# Can't dynamically add new textbox to <div> tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've been on this for more than a half a day and I can't figure out what I'm missing. I've tried many different iterations and every other solution I could find. It should be a no-brainer. I am using JQueryMobile 1.2 and it's dependencies Here's the javascript (note `var counter = 2;` *is* declared above the code:

```
    $("#btn_addIngredient").click(function () {      
        if (counter > 10) {
            alert("Please limit to 10 ingredients");
            return false;
        }   

        var newIngredientTextBox = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'div_ingredient' + counter);         

        newIngredientTextBox.after().html('<input type="text" name="ingredient' + counter + 
              '" id="ingredient' + counter + '" value="#' + counter + '" >');

        newIngredientTextBox.appendTo("#allIngredientsDiv"); 
        counter++;

    }); //~ $("#btn_addIngredient")
```

And the html:

```
     <div id="IngredientsTextGroup" data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset id="IngredientsFieldset" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
            <div id="allIngredientsDiv">
                Ingredients
                <div id="div_ingredient1">
                    <input id="ingredient1" value="#1" type="text">
                </div>

                <!-- *** Need to add <div_ingredient2, 3 ...>  -->

            </div>
            <a id="btn_addIngredient" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus"
                             data-iconpos="left">
                Add Ingredient
            </a>
    <div>
```

Comment: `.after().html(str)` doesn't make sense. What it really does is set the html of the div to `str`, `.after` is skipped over due to it having no html content to append after the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) wrong.. If you want the element to after your selected element then do this

```
newIngredientTextBox.after('<input type="text" name="ingredient' + counter + 
          '" id="ingredient' + counter + '" value="#' + counter + '" />');
```

If you want it to be inside div element then you can use .append()

```
newIngredientTextBox.append('<input type="text" name="ingredient' + counter + 
          '" id="ingredient' + counter + '" value="#' + counter + '" />');
```

Also you need to append the element after you add it to the dom.. not before

```
newIngredientTextBox.appendTo("#allIngredientsDiv").after('<input type="text" name="ingredient' + counter + 
          '" id="ingredient' + counter + '" value="#' + counter + '" />');
```

Comment: my understanding was it was to be after the div :/?

Comment: It could have been either actually.. as he used `.after() - next` and `.html() - inside`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var counter = 2;
var newIngredientTextBox = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'div_ingredient' + counter);         
console.info(newIngredientTextBox);
newIngredientTextBox.after('<input type="text" name="ingredient' + counter +  '" id="ingredient' + counter + '" value="#' + counter + '" >');
```

after then added html won't work

Comment: Hmmm.. Thanks for your response, @JamieHutber. Still no luck, it seems that either the DOM isn't being refreshed, or I'm missing something that's causing the browser to simply ignore the code. Am I right in thinking the premise of the code is solid? I smell something stupid that I'm doing and can't for the life of me figure out what.